# Is it possible to move threads from one forum to another in Ploneboard forums?

Tags: plone, forum

Currently, we use Plone 3.3.5 with Ploneboard 2.2 and we have several forums for different topics on our site. Sometimes users post their messages in a wrong forum and we would like to move those threads to the appropriate forum. Unfortunately, this does not work.

More precisely:
When displaying a thread "xyz" in forum "A", I can use the Actions>Cut drop-down menu and get the message that "xyz" was cut. But it did not happen, "xyz" is still in forum "A". When I subsequently use the Actions>Paste drop-down menu in forum "B", I get the message that pasting pages is not allowed. When I do the same thing in a thread "abc" in forum "B" instead, nothing happens.

My question is if Ploneboard is designed to cut a thread in one forum and paste it into another or if this functionality is simply not provided.

We plan to upgrade to Plone 4. Is it possible to move threads from one forum to another in a more recent version of Ploneboard? If not, is there an alternative message board/ forum solution with this feature?

Comment: "this does not work". How does it not work? Do you get an error? Please be more specific.

Comment: When displaying a thread "xyz" in forum "A", I can use the Actions>Cut drop-down menu and get the message that "xyz" was cut. But it did not happen, "xyz" is still in forum "A". When I subsequently use the Actions>Paste drop-down menu in forum "B", I get the message that pasting pages is not allowed. When I do the same thing in a thread "abc" in forum "B" instead, nothing happens. 

My question is if Ploneboard is designed to cut a thread in one forum and paste it into another or if this functionality is simply not provided.

Comment: Sure, but telling us what you tried is fundamental to us being able to help you better. Please edit your question to include the fact that you tried to cut and paste the item to try and move it.

Answer (score 3):

I've found your same problem.
For Plone 3.3.x I've developed this product: Products.PloneboardPasteObject
You can find it on pypi: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PloneboardPasteObject

Comment: How about just fixing Ploneboard? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend firing up a test instance of Plone 4 and trying out the latest release of Ploneboard (3.3).  Because threads are simply content objects, I wouldn't think Ploneboard would need to do anything particular to "support" cut-and-paste of threads.  So, my guess is that either A) it is a bug, and might be fixed in a more recent version or B) there is some deep reason why this can't be supported, in which case it is not likely to have changed in a more recent release.

Answer (score 0):

A `Ploneboard` allows `PloneboardForum`s. A PloneboardForum allows `PloneboardConversation`s. A PloneboardConversation allows `PloneboardComment`s.

See:

- https://github.com/collective/Products.Ploneboard/tree/master/Products/Ploneboard/profiles/default/types

For more information. Particularly, see the following properties for each of the above types (this one is from Ploneboard.xml):

```
 <property name="filter_content_types">True</property>
 <property name="allowed_content_types">
  <element value="PloneboardForum"/>
 </property>
```

You can only paste objects inside other objects that permit the object type you are trying to paste. **This is how Plone works in general** and is not Ploneboard specific.

Re: Plone 4. Upgrading does not change this basic Plone feature.

Re: Other Plone forum software: Using other forum software does not change this basic Plone feature, with the possible exception of the other forum software defining different content types and constraints.